# preposition "to" vs "of"

Tags: grammar

> A: Ava turns around and with the expression suddenly displayed in her eyes, Andy standing before her proved to be the one to her heart's desire.
>
> B: Ava turns around and with the expression suddenly displayed in her eyes, Andy standing before her proved to be the one of her heart's desire.

Are both A and B acceptable?

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking on the "edit" button right below the "grammar" tag. By the way, you also want an apostropohs in "heart's".

Answer (score 0):

Why not say "proved to be her heart's desire?" It's less verbose and more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Of
Used for belonging to, relating to, or connected with:

The secret of this game is that you can’t ever win.

Used to indicate reference:

I got married in the summer of 2000.
This is a picture of my family.

Used to indicate an amount or number:

I drank three cups of milk.
A large number of people gathered to protest.

To
Used to indicate the place, person, or thing that someone or something moves toward, or the direction of something:

I am heading to the entrance of the building.
The package was mailed to Mr. Kim yesterday.

Used to indicate a limit or an ending point:

The snow was piled up to the roof.

Used to indicate relationship:

This letter is very important to your admission.
My answer to your question is in this envelop.

Used to indicate a time or a period:

I work nine to six, Monday to Friday.
It is now 10 to five. (In other words, it is 4:50.)

But on looking closely to your sentence I think both A and B 
are acceptable because both of them are showing up the same feeling towards the Andy.

$[But I will prefer 'of' in place of 'to' because of shows it more clearly]$